# WPF XAML - Bind datagrid column to foreign key (Dataset)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ms-access, datagrid

I am developing a simple WPF application that talks to an Access 2000 database. I have used entity framework in the past, but it seems I am limited with an Access database. I managed to generate a DataSet xsd file, that contains mappings for each table and the relations between tables. The schema is shown below:

[image: db schema]

To bind the data to a WPF datagrid, I set the DataContext to a DataSet, after filling it from various table adapters. I use the following C# to achieve this in the WPF code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{   
    private TillDataSet ds = new TillDataSet();
    private TransactionTableAdapter transactionDa = new TransactionTableAdapter();
    private DentistTableAdapter dentistDa = new DentistTableAdapter();
    private Transaction_TypeTableAdapter transactionTypeDa = new Transaction_TypeTableAdapter();
    private Payment_MethodTableAdapter paymentMethodDa = new Payment_MethodTableAdapter();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void fillDataAdapters()
    {
        transactionDa.Fill(ds.Transaction);
        dentistDa.Fill(ds.Dentist);
        transactionTypeDa.Fill(ds.Transaction_Type);
        paymentMethodDa.Fill(ds.Payment_Method);
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        fillDataAdapters();
        this.DataContext = ds;
    }
}
```

I want to display a WPF datagrid, that contains details from the Transaction Table. I am able to retrieve the basic details from within the Transaction table. What I want to achieve is to be able to navigate the relationships the table has, such that I can display the Dentists name, instead of the foreign key value. I have tried the following XAML:

```
<!--Transaction List-->
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="dtgTransactions" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Transaction}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Trans_Date}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dentist" Binding="{Binding Dentist.Dentist_Name}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Payment Method" Binding="{Binding Method}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Notice the binding under the Dentist column. When I try this, I get an empty data column. How can I navigate the relationship using XAML?

Comment: I dont have any query, the data comes directly from DataContext. MS Access interaction is made through OLEDB, which does not have an enity framework provider. Otherwise I could form LINQ queries and include the navigation properties. I was indeed looking for some sort of load option setting, but did not get far.

Comment: Try to add Dataset relations, maybe something like this: 
 ds.Relations.Add("TransactionsDentists", ds.Tables["Transaction"].Columns["DentistID"], ds.Tables["Dentists"].Columns["DentistID"])

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried adding the relations, but got an exception that a relation already existed between the child and parent. This at least shows that the relation is in place. I did find that I can navigate the relation in code behind. I can do the following:   MessageBox.Show(ds.Transaction.First().DentistRow.Dentist_Name); If I try to navigate the DentistRow property from the XAML, it still fails....

Comment: are there any binding errors, go to Debug -> Windows -> Output

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is a full example of working example.  Please edit this so we can see where the issue is.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded" >
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Name="dtgTransactions" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Transaction}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Trans_Date}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Dentist">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Dentists}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dentist_Name}"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

> ```
>     using System;
>     using System.Collections.Generic;
>     using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
>     using System.Linq;
>     using System.Text;
>     using System.Threading.Tasks;
>
>     namespace WpfApplication1
>     {
>       public class ViewModel
>       {
>         public Transactions Transaction { get; set; }
>
>         public ViewModel()
>         {
>           Transaction = new Transactions();
>
>           Transaction transData = new Transaction();
>           transData.ID = 0;
>           transData.Trans_Date = DateTime.Now;
>           transData.Type = "Type1";
>
>           Dentist dentistData = new Dentist();
>           dentistData.ID = 0;
>           dentistData.Dentist_Name = "Dentist1 Name";
>           transData.Dentists.Add(dentistData);
>
>           Transaction.Add(transData);
>
>           transData = new Transaction();
>           transData.ID = 1;
>           transData.Trans_Date = DateTime.Now;
>           transData.Type = "Type2";
>
>           dentistData = new Dentist();
>           dentistData.ID = 1;
>           dentistData.Dentist_Name = "Dentist2 Name";
>           transData.Dentists.Add(dentistData);
>
>           dentistData = new Dentist();
>           dentistData.ID = 2;
>           dentistData.Dentist_Name = "Dentist3 Name";
>           transData.Dentists.Add(dentistData);
>
>
>           Transaction.Add(transData);
>         }
>       }
>
>
>       public class Transactions : ObservableCollection<Transaction>
>       {
>         public ObservableCollection<Transaction> TransactionList { get; set; }
>
>         public Transactions()
>         {
>           TransactionList = new ObservableCollection<Transaction>();
>         }
>       }
>
>
>       public class Transaction
>       {
>         public ObservableCollection<Dentist> Dentists { get; set; }
>         public int ID { get; set; }
>         public DateTime Trans_Date { get; set; }
>         public string Type { get; set; }
>
>         public Transaction()
>         {
>           Dentists = new ObservableCollection<Dentist>();
>         }
>
>       }
>
>
>       public class Dentist
>       {
>         public int ID { get; set; }
>         public string Dentist_Name { get; set; }
>       }
>
>     }
> ```

Comment: Aw this looked promising. Unfortunately, same result...just an empty value shown :( Thanks for trying

Comment: can you paste all your classes Transaction, Dentist.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your table have *Dentist* name and you are binding with *Dentist**s***

Anyway, try this;

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.Dentist,
 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
```

And;

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Dentist_Name}"/>
```

Comment: Are you responding to the question or the other answer?

Comment: To first question.