# How do you XAML bind data from a related table into a datagrid column?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, visual-studio-2012

A stack overflow user @JTK posted a question here [WPF/Dataset: How do you XAML bind data from a related table into a datagrid column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27577970/wpf-dataset-how-do-you-xaml-bind-data-from-a-related-table-into-a-datagrid-colu)

No answer is found there so i am posting here. @HighCore commented to use EF. I am using EF and facing the same issue.

I have a table called delivery which has foreign key columns like transporter_id, pump_id. Now this columns refers to other tables like transporter table which has two columns (transporter_id and transporter_name)

How to display the actual name rather than id column in GUI? I also need to update them from GUI. How to achieve update and delete?